# Count the number of times a value appears in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I have a simple  multi-dimensional array that looks like below. I am trying to count how many times each value exists in the array (i.e. arthritis => 3). I have tried all the different count PHP functions but it always returns a number and not a key => value pair. I have also looked on SO for similar questions, but nothing really fits the simplicity of my array.

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(0) "Arthritis"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "Thyroid"
        [1]=>
        string(10) " Arthritis"
        [2]=>
        string(11) " Autoimmune"
        [3]=>
        string(7) " Cancer"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(6) {
        [0]=>
        string(7) "Anxiety"
        [1]=>
        string(10) " Arthritis"
        [2]=>
        string(11) " Autoimmune"
        [3]=>
        string(15) " Bone and Joint"
        [4]=>
        string(7) " Cancer"
        [5]=>
        string(8) " Candida"
      }

     }

<?php
print_r(count($items, COUNT_RECURSIVE));
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to flatten it into a single dimension using `array_merge()` on the sub-arrays, and then count the values using `array_count_values()`:

```
$count = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $items));
```

Comment: thanks, didnt know it could be solved in one line, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a custom loop:

```
$counts = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $disease) { // $disease here is the string like "Arthritis"
        if (isset($counts[$disease])) // $disease then become the key for the resulting array
            $counts[$disease]++;
        else
            $counts[$disease] = 1;
    }
}
print_r($counts);
```

Comment: wow, so simple, was racking my brain for hours -- you think you can how u got the name to appear? thanks a bunch saved me.

Comment: @DEM I added some comments that might help. You should look at AbraCadaver 's answer too, I think his is the best (and simplest).

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the comments -- looked @abraCadaver's , thanks for the help!